# Weird throttling effect when consuming AWS based services

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, throttling, rate-limits

So here's the thing: I am observing the mentioned effect for some time now and I don't get it. It starts to really annoy me and I cannot get a grip on it. So I am turning to this community with the hope for help.

#### What is my situation?

I have two situations in which the effect occurs:

1. When initializing terraform which downloads all the necessary plugins every time.
2. When updating my vagrant boxes.

The common denominator here seems to be that in both situations the actual data is located on AWS.

#### What is the effect?

The effect is - plain and easy - that the download throughput drops below the bit measurement. Like it does not say 12 kbit/s but rather 12 bit/s. No network connection - not internal nor external - shows at least a similar situation. Also the effect is not persistent. Sometimes it occurs, sometimes not.

Here is a live example of the situation when updating a vagrant box:

```
Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/bento/boxes/ubuntu-18.04/versions/202012.21.0/providers/virtualbox.box
Download redirected to host: vagrantcloud-files-production.s3.amazonaws.com
Progress: 0% (Rate: 7092/s, Estimated time remaining: 8:54:17)
```

*The worst part is, that this is a good rate actually.*

Can anyone point me into a direction on how to tackle this? I really cannot get a grip.

I will update this question as soon as information arrives.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on what "weird throttling effect" is supposed to mean?

Comment: I totally missed that, thanks! Hope I could make myself more clear now?

Comment: Sounds like you are having problems communicating with AWS.  This happening on all devices connected to your network or just a specific machine?

Comment: I only have one device available currently, my Linux workstation. I would need to get another device for testing. Problem is, that this effect is not persistent. Sometimes it is as bad as described above, sometimes it is fine.